# SQL Express 2014 Installation Fails with SSL Error

Tags: sql-server-express

I've got a user that wants to install SQL Server Express 2014 on his Windows 10 laptop. The default installation fails:

```
2017-11-13 13:39:31.31 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )

2017-11-13 13:39:31.31 Server      UTC adjustment: 1:00
2017-11-13 13:39:31.31 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.31 Server      All rights reserved.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      Server process ID is 5868.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Dell Inc.', System Model: 'Latitude 7280'.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2017-11-13 13:39:31.32 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "SQLEXPRESS"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -Q
     -q "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 3659
     -T 3610
     -T 8015
     -d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data\master.mdf"
     -l "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data\mastlog.ldf"
2017-11-13 13:39:31.58 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.58 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.58 Server      Detected 16265 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.58 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.66 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2017-11-13 13:39:31.69 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.73 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2017-11-13 13:39:31.74 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2017-11-13 13:39:31.74 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 8668 at 11/13/2017 1:39:30 PM (local) 11/13/2017 12:39:30 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.74 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.75 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.77 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.77 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.77 spid8s      Warning ******************
2017-11-13 13:39:31.78 spid8s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.78 spid8s      Starting up database 'master'.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.79 spid8s      1 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.80 spid8s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.89 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.94 spid8s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.94 spid8s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:31.98 spid8s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2017-11-13 13:39:31.98 spid8s      Server name is 'SWSTW10WRBRT\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.00 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x80090331. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm. 
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm. 
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-11-13 13:39:32.04 spid14s     SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
```

Will he have to manually create a certificate, or is there a way to disable the SSL requirement during the installation? The installation is for local testing purposes only, so security isn't a concern.

Thanks!
Oli

Comment: Have you checked out the installation account. I mean to say that from which account you are installing that have credential of installation or not.

Comment: Can you go to SQL Server configuration manager and change SQL Server service account to `NT Authority\System` and restart the service. This ofcourse is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As per **Pinal Dave sqlauthority blog** 
[Here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/27/sql-server-sql-installation-fails-error-code-0x851a001a-wait-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed/)

if you shall get the below mention error

> Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the
>   SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about
>   possible related problems.

**Cause**

May be in which account you have selected during installation.  Since this is a domain controller, I thought that there might be issues.

**WORKAROUND / SOLUTION**

As the error says, first we need to uninstall the feature and then during setup, when we come to Server Configuration Screen, we need to change the account name of the Database Engine Service to

```
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE.
```

Both worked for my client and they could install SQL Express.